# How to implement a widget that is adaptive to available space, shrinking part of itself when space is unavailable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to accomplish an ostensibly simple layout requirement in Flutter, but am struggling with fulfilling the details of the requirements. I want a widget that displays some text under an image. The image should take whatever available space it has, but shrink if it does not have enough space.

My first attempt was simply:

```dart
class VerticalLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final column = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: LabeledImage(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: LabeledImage(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: LabeledImage(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: LabeledImage(),
        ),
      ],
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    );

    final scaffold = Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: column),
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );

    return scaffold;
  }
}

class LabeledImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final image = FlutterLogo(size: 250);
    final text = Text('foo');
    final column = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: image,
        ),
        text,
      ],
    );

    return column;
  }
}
```

This works fine for situations where the image is large enough (as with `size: 250` above):

[image]

But when the image is smaller, the `Expanded` causes the image to take up more space than required:

[image]

OK, so `Expanded` doesn't seem like the right choice because I don't really want the image to expand if it cannot fill the space. The next likeliest candidate seemed like `FittedBox`:

```dart
class LabeledImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final image = FlutterLogo(size: 50);
    final text = Text('foo');
    final column = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        FittedBox(
          child: image,
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        ),
        text,
      ],
    );

    return column;
  }
}
```

Now the `VerticalLayout` works great in situations where the image is small (as above):

[image]

But it fails to shrink the image when it's big:

[image]

I want my `LabeledImage` widget to also work when inside a `Row`, but I can't even find a way to have it "just work" inside a `Column`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

### working Vertical and Horizontal Layout

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VerticalLayout();
//    return HorizontalLayout();
  }
}

class HorizontalLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final int itemCount = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final row = Row(
      children: List.generate(itemCount, (_) => HorizontalLabeledImage()).toList(),
    );

    final scaffold = Scaffold(
      body: row,
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );

    return scaffold;
  }
}
class HorizontalLabeledImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(//doesn't matter Flexible or Expanded
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          FittedBox(child: FlutterLogo()),
          Text('foobar', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class VerticalLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final int itemCount = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final column = Column(
      children: List.generate(itemCount, (_) => VerticalLabeledImage()).toList(),
    );

    final scaffold = Scaffold(
      body: column,
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );

    return scaffold;
  }
}

class VerticalLabeledImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(//doesn't matter Flexible or Expanded
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: FittedBox(child: FlutterLogo())),
          Text('foobar'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works for a `Column` (vertical) layout. In a `Row`, you have to change to `BoxFit.fitWidth` _and_ the label gets pushed all the way to the bottom of the screen rather than sitting underneath the image.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to find something that pretty much works by combining your initial response with another I received via Slack (neither worked on their own). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58073514/5380).

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at something that seems to work pretty well by combining the answer from @Doc with an answer I received via Slack:

```dart
class LabeledImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final image = FlutterLogo(size: 50);
    final text = Text('foo');
    final column = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: FittedBox(
            child: image,
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
          ),
        ),
        text,
      ],
    );
    return column;
  }
}
```

I don't fully understand *why* this works, and it's a bit finicky to use when composing widgets together in different ways. For example, once I had a working `VerticalLayout` and `HorizontalLayout`, I then tried stacking multiple `HorizontalLayout` widgets on top of each other in another `Column`. I had to wrap each widget in `Flexible` for it to work, and I don't really understand why.